# I just wanted to know the functionality of readInput() in the code below

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

I want to know the purpose of the [`readInput()` function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUCvD.jpg)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rainbow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rainbowColors[] = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green",
                                  "Blue", "Indigo", "Violet"};
        int choice = readInput(); // **whats this?
        System.out.println("Your choice is: "+rainbowColors[choice-1]);  
    }

    public static int readInput(){ *and this
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer from 1 - 7");
        int input = s.nextInt();
        return(input);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's called a method (or ***function*** in other programming languages) which has the sole purpose of getting keyboard input from the User running your application with regards to a specific color choice made available within the `rainbowColors[]` String Array. A literal value is expected from the User which is then subtracted by 1 to get the actual array index value for the related color.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a normal function instead of writing scanner class object for every input and getting specified input we can create a function like this so  we can reuse the code.